# Basket price rules - Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I tried to set up a basket price rule: save 25 when you spend £300 or more on specific products.

**condition:**
subtotal equals or greater than 300
product attribute combination: category contains "the specific product"
**Action**
fix amount for the whole basket: 25

However, the rule always applies when customers spend more than £300 and contains the specific product. It doesn't require them to spend more than £300 on the specific products.

Anyone knows how to set up this kind of rule? I want customers spend £300 on the specific products, and the basket could contain a few different products??

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming question. Sorry.